# Crystal Report SP13 asks UserID and Password to connect to SQL Server 2014 db

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, sql-server-2014-express

I am using Crystal Report SP13 in Visual Studio 2013. I attempted to connect to SQL server 2014 database engine with Windows Authentication that does not have userid and password. But every time I access the windows form application in VB.Net 2013, a popup box asks for userid and password. When I gave Windows account's Username and Password, it doesn't works. If it is not able to connect to SQL server with Windows Authentication, how to convert existing database engine to SQL server 2014 authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the CLIENT DRIVER.

I don't know neither WHY nor how solve this problem (i have the same here) butm if you change the SQL CLIENT DRIVER for 2005, the problem will stop.

And before you asking me, no, there is no problem nor lack of performance doing this.

Good luck!